# Is there a solution for a contest using the Twitter tweet and Facebook like button as votes?

Tags: facebook, button, twitter

We have a matrix of images for each entry like this http://www.tripleships.com and want to create a contest by talling up the tweets and facebook likes for each image/entry.  The problem with this though is that the tweets are not unique, the same people can retweet it as much as they want, and the tweet history are only available for three days (We would like to have voting go on for a week).

Is there a solution for a contest using the Twitter tweet and Facebook like button as votes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For tweets

1. Require a hashtag to vote
2. Check and cache results each day
3. Keep track of each user, and count votes one time per user

Comment: Thank you for responding.  How would I cache the results?  I was thinking of using javascript like this http://remysharp.com/2007/05/18/add-twitter-to-your-blog-step-by-step/comment-page-10/#comment-273491 so I could see the votes because if it was just a twitter button, it would only cache the button.  Twitter.com only keeps about 3 days of tweets.  How do I cache the tweets/retweets?

Comment: You need to write a process that runs on your servers each day (perhaps a few times a day) and looks for votes and saves them somewhere.  Whatever you were planning to do to count the votes at the end, but do it a few times a day to make sure you don't lose them.

Answer (score 0):

As per facebook https://www.facebook.com/page_guidelines.php#promotionsguidelines

> v.    You must not use Facebook features or functionality, such as the Like button, as a voting mechanism for a promotion.

So you cant use FB likes as a voting mechanism.